# angularjs ngclick dealing with two function

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Help make angularjs ng click dealing with two functions. I tried but it is not working. theshowtakeorder shows and hide a div and the takeorderfunction must execute a function from the controller.

```
<button ng-click="takeorderfunction() showtakeorder = !showtakeorder">TAKE ORDER</button>
```

Comment: Create third function which call both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a semi-colon:

```
<button ng-click="takeorderfunction(); showtakeorder = !showtakeorder">TAKE ORDER</button>
```

Or better yet place your logic in another function:

```
<button ng-click="clickFunction()">TAKE ORDER</button>
```

controller:

```
$scope.clickFunction = function(){
    takeorderfunction();
    showtakeorder = !showtakeorder;
}
```